# How to make visible a ManyToManyField from UserProfile in User admin tab (Django-Admin)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

How to make `ManyToMany` attribute of `UserProfile` (which has attribute `user = OneToOne(User)` visible in `Django-Admin`?

So there is a common `User` model which I use to login/registration. This `User` model is extended by using `OneToOneField(User,related_name='userprofile')` in `UserProfile` model.

`UserProfile` has `ManyToManyField` attribute:

`languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, through='UserProfileLanguage')`

And this is the problem.

I can't see `languages` in `User` tab in `Django-Admin`.
I can see all `UserProfile` attributes in `User` tab because I did this:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'User_Profile'

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )
```

But only attribute of `UserProfile` I can't see in `User` tab is `languages`. I've read that it is probably because it's `ManyToManyField` but I can't find out how to put it inside the `User` tab.

I tried to put it as an inline model but it raises error:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'User_Profile'

class UserProfileLanguageLevelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfileLanguage
    # THIS DOES NOT WORK EITHER: model = User.userprofile.languages.through

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, UserProfileLanguageLevelInline)

<class 'SolutionsForLanguagesApp.admin.UserProfileLanguageLevelInline'>: (admin.
E202) 'SolutionsForLanguagesApp.UserProfileLanguage' has no ForeignKey to 'auth.
User'.
```

It's because `languages` is an attribute of `UserProfile`, not `User` but I don' know how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you can see `languages` but not edit the field in `User` tab should use `readonly_fields`:

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'User_Profile'
    readonly_fields = ('languages',)

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )
```

Comment: Thank you Javier, the best would be if I could change the languages and leves. This is possible to make it work in Userprofile tab but not in User tab this way. Do you know what to do? Thank you very much

Comment: I expound what I think is, in your first example the reason is `through='UserProfileLanguage'` creates a intermediate table `app_userprofile_languages`that it easier the ORM filtering but fail to understand why the data is not exposed or not there is any warning. 
So if you don't use `through` you could see `languages`. In second example when you `admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)` model `UserProfileLanguage`don't have FK to `User` and if you did show the fields in that table. I hope explained, and if someone else can help understand this.